# Reinstall mysql and keep mysql data

Tags: mysql, debian

In Debian, /root/bin folder was deleted.

The biggest problem is that mysql is missing. When I type:

```
> mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I have all data in /var/lib/mysql. How do I install mysql back without harming my data?

Here is what I see, when I search for mysql:

[image]

Is it true that I don't have mysql executable, so that I can do

```
full/path/to/mysql -v
```

Comment: Install mysql like any other package? What does deleting `/root/bin` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you delete `/root/bin`, or did you delete ***`/bin`***?

If the former you shouldn't have lost anything (root should ***NEVER*** have "user binaries" in `~/bin` - if you do you're *doing it wrong* and should stop).

If the latter (and that's really where MySQL is installed on your system), reinstall the MySQL package (as well as everything else you've undoubtedly destroyed int he process!) as Michael Hampton suggested.

---

This is a case where you should really be restoring the lost files from backups (and being ***WAY*** more careful with the `rm` command in the future!). You happen to have lucked out, since as long as the MySQL data directory is safe all you need to do is get the binaries for the appropriate version of MySQL, install them appropriately, and start the MySQL server with your existing data directory.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, because I cannot find mysql anywhere. I cannot find mysqladmin either. Say, the following command - find / -name mysqladmin - does not return anything. Is it possible that because of some stupid occasion mysql resided in /root/bin?

Comment: Anything is possible - if you have encountered such a system you should rebuild it to be sane (and migrate your data)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the database and most of your system is intact IF all you deleted was /root/bin.  What I suspect is that you might have deleted perhaps more of the /root directory, like that containing the environment for the root user (i.e. .profile).  Thus you have not properly set PATH and thus the command is not found.

Answer (score 1):

First please take a backup (cp to any other location) of /var/lib/mysql before doing anything 
In debian you can install mysql  and mysql-server with apt-get

```
   apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Once installation done start Mysql and all should be fine.